# What is the complexity difference between the two various ways of initialization of Array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, time-complexity

What is the complexity difference between the two various ways of initialization of Array in Ruby?

I need to initialize my new Array to 0.

I could do either of the ways:

```
newArray = Array.new(a,0)
```

or

```
newArray = Array.new(a){|i| i*0}
```

I need to know the difference between the time complexity if any?

Comment: `{|i| i*0}` makes absolutely no sense, since it’s the same as `{0}`. Did you mean `[0] * a`?

Comment: Yes it is same as {0}

Comment: So, `[0] * a` is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. Let's make use of `benchmark` module and see how the two variations perform on scale.

```
Benchmark.realtime do |x|
  10_000.times { Array.new(1000, 0) }
end
#=> 0.032521000131964684
Benchmark.realtime do |x|
  10_000.times { Array.new(1000) { 0 } }
end
#=> 0.49374799989163876
```

As you can see, the first implementation is n times faster than block initialization. According to `Array.new` [description](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-c-new), the last form populates each element by passing the element's index to the block and storing the return value. In this version, there should be intermediate variable creation and storing which takes space and CPU.

```
    if (rb_block_given_p()) {
        long i;

        if (argc == 2) {
            rb_warn("block supersedes default value argument");
        }
        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            rb_ary_store(ary, i, rb_yield(LONG2NUM(i)));
            ARY_SET_LEN(ary, i + 1);
        }
    }
```

vs

```
ary_memfill(ary, 0, len, val);
```

`ary_memfill` iterates in O(n) and sets the values [[ref]](https://github.com/brightbox/deb-ruby2.1/blob/master/array.c#L51-L56). `rb_ary_store` (in former) uses [`rb_ary_modify`](https://github.com/brightbox/deb-ruby2.1/blob/a5f8178710019f59ae29eea6ffc598a3652966d2/array.c#L314) which does it's own set of computations.

Comment: `n times faster` ? No. 0.49374799989163876 / 0.032521000131964684 is about 15.

Comment: Oops. Didn't mean  n as in arrays length there.